# How to use swagger with query params deserialising to class?

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I have spring rest controller and i want it documented via swagger. It looks like this:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Returns comments list")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public CollectionResponse<CommentDTO> getComments(CommentFilterDTO filterDTO) {
    Page<CommentEntity> requisitionComments = commentService.getComments(filterDTO);
    return Convert.convert(requisitionComments, COMMENT_ENTITY_2_COMMENT_DTO);
}
```

CommentsFilterDTO is

```
public class CommentFilterDTO {
  private Long requisitionId;//get, set
  private CommentType commentType;//get, set
  // etc
}
```

This controller takes query string with pageable and filterDTO params like this:

```
my/comments?requisitionId=1&commentType=COMMENT
```

Now i'm trying to document it via swagger and i want all possible query parameters documented as well, but if i leave it like this i see only
[image]
I can document query params via @ApiImplicitParams like

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
  @ApiImplicitParam(name = "requisitionId", value = "Requisition id", required = true, dataType = "long", paramType = "query"),
  ...   
})
```

Is there any way to tell swagger what all CommentFilterDTO fields can be used as query parameters?